# Hide Div after treeview loads and its in an updatepanel

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

This control is on the master page in an update panel and is loaded after user interaction (click). The div containing the "loading" text does not hide. I want to hide it after the control is fully rendered.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HierarchicalViewNonXML.ascx.cs" EnableViewState ="true" Inherits="Website.UserControls.HierarchicalViewNonXML" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<div id="loadDIV" class="loading" >Loading  ****   </div> 
<div id="treeDIV"><telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server" Height="100%" CssClass="noScroll" CausesValidation="false" EnableViewState="true"  OnNodeClick="RadTreeView1_NodeClick" OnNodeDataBound="RadTreeView1_NodeDataBound" ></telerik:RadTreeView></div> 

<style type="text/css">
    .loading {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //$(document).ready(function() {
    //    $('#loadDIV').delay(30000).hide();
    //});
    $(document).load(function () {
        var loadDIV = document.getElementById("loadDIV");   
        loadDIV.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    });
    //$("#loadDIV").hide();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an UpdatePanel you need to hide the loading div after Partial PostBack. You can use the `PageRequestManager` for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    manager.add_endRequest(function () {
        var loadDIV = document.getElementById("loadDIV");
        loadDIV.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    });
</script>
```

Or use a ScriptManager in code behind to call a javascript function.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "hideDiv", "hideLoadingDiv();", true);
```

Comment: I owe you a beer :-)

Comment: I would love a cold one!